# How to write about simple locomotion?

Tags: third-person

I am writing a third person story, the opening contains a short tram ride which the main character is on, how can I write such a scene without just writing;

The tram moved forward another 100 metres and $main_character saw something.

Answer (score 2):

Go ride a tram. you'll answer your own question within 10 mins.

Alternatively, use the moment to give the reader something useful. Otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time.

Set location:

> He watched as they slid past an open-air market, with eager, healthy-looking traders boasting tables of blah blah blah...

Set mood:

> The tram wheels ground against old steel, dragging Sven yard by yard to his fate...

Define character:

> Those kids spoke again. Their shrill, excited voices annoying every passenger except Agnes. She could listen to that sound for hours...

Advance plot:

> The tram rolled past a scene of sudden urgency, with police officers unloading from three black cars...

And if none of those fit, get it over with quickly:

> A moment later...